# Bypassing htmlspecialchars() for XSS (Reflected) and using an event handler is not an option in this case

Tags: xss, reflected-xss, dvwa

I am trying to bypass high security XSS on DVWA. So the vulnerable code(I highly doubt that is it *really* vulnerable?) is:-

```
<?php 

if(!array_key_exists ("name", $_GET) || $_GET['name'] == NULL || $_GET['name'] == ''){ 

 $isempty = true; 

} else { 

 echo '<pre>'; 
 echo 'Hello ' . htmlspecialchars($_GET['name']); 
 echo '</pre>'; 

}

?>
```

And the url is
 `http://localhost/dvwa/vulnerabilities/xss_r/?name=<payload>#`

It is clear that application is using `htmlspecialchars()` which will convert all html characters like `<`, `>` into its corresponding html entity. And If I encode my payload

`<img src=x onerror=alert(1)>`

It will result into

`&lt;img src=x onerror=alert(1)&gt;`

which will be eventually rendered as

`<img src=x onerror=alert(1)>`

and also using an event handler is not an option since the user input is rendered *within* the `pre` tag and there is no place for adding an 
attribute.

So what can I do to bypass `htmlspecialchars()`?

Comment: you need to decode the char.. i'm sure you gonna make it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be from [xss_r/source/impossible.php](https://github.com/ethicalhack3r/DVWA/blob/v1.9/vulnerabilities/xss_r/source/impossible.php). In the *impossible* level the vulnerabilities have been fixed, so they are not intended to be vulnerable.